# Docker is trying to pull all nuget packages from private repo

Tags: docker, nuget

Docker is trying to pull all nuget packages from my private repo (things like entity framework core). My nuget.config file has an entry for both the private repo and the standard nuget repo.

Is there a way around this?

Relevant part of dockerfile

COPY NuGet.Config ./

RUN dotnet restore "MyProjFolder/MyProj.csproj" --configfile NuGet.Config

Thanks in advance

Comment: When NuGet looks for a package, it requests the package from all package sources at the same time and takes the first response it gets back. It's completely normal/expected that package sources return a 404 for packages it doesn't have. Is it actually causing you a problem?

Comment: You can change the order of the sources in the `NuGet.Config` to reduce the noise. But as @zivkan mentioned, 404 is not an issue because `dotnet` just tries to find the package in all sources one by one.

Comment: @VladimirSerykh the order of sources don't matter. Since NuGet 3, it sends requests to all sources in parallel and takes the first response it receives. Even the fastest network with the slowest computer, NuGet will be able to make requests to all sources more quickly than the fastest one can respond.